# Calling CMT bean from BMT bean results in "Local transaction already has 1 non-XA Resource"

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1, jta

I have one EJB with Bean-Managed transaction:

```
@Singleton
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class BmtBean {

  @Resource
  private DataSource ds1;

  @Resource
  private SessionContext sessionCtx;

  @EJB
  private CmtBean cmtBean;

  public void callCmtBean() {
    Connection conn1 = null;
    try {
      conn1 = ds1.getConnection();
      // create a PreparedStatement and execute a query
      // process result set
      while(resultSet.next()) {
        // map resultSet to an entity
        Entity entity = mapResultSetToEntity(resultSet);
        sessionCtx.getUserTransaction().begin();
        // pass an entity to another EJB,
        // that operates on a different JTA data source
        cmtBean.call(entity);
        sessionCtx.getUserTransaction().commit();
      }
    } finally {
      // release connection
    }
  }
}
```

And another bean with container-managed transaction:

```
@Singleton
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class CmtBean {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
  public void call(Entity entities) {
    //persist passed entities
    //em.flush()
    //em.clear();
  }

}
```

Calling `cmtBean#call` doesn't cause `TransactionRequiredException`, because prior to that I start a `UserTransaction`. But when `em#flush` is called, this exception is thrown:

> Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in
>   allocating a connection. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Local
>   transaction already has 1 non-XA Resource: cannot add more resources.

After digging some EclipseLink code, I see that when calling `em#flush()` it attempts to obtain a new connection from `dataSource` and fails to do so.

Is this a bug or expected behaviour? How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**
See the updated code example.

Also, I have to stress, that **I do use 2 non-XA JTA data sources**. But since the connection in `BmtBean` is by default set to `autocommit`, by the time `CmtBean` is called, the transaction has to be already commited.

Comment: Configuration is missing, as the persistence unit should be obtaining the connection from a JTA datasource and so not get this problem.  Check out the app server examples here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA

Comment: @Chris What do you mean `configuration is missing`? I have a `persistence.xml` with proper settings for `jta-data-source`. See the update. I also improved the code example.

Comment: You haven't specified the server you are using, the persistence.xml or any other config setup used to tie the JTA pool to your transaction, so the demos listed are a good starting point you can use to compare what you have with what is known to work.  If your JTA pool is listed with the transaction correctly, it should return the connection associated to the transaction and not try to enlist another one.  So you might not be using the right connection pool or configured it incorrectly.